# User identifying with uploading a file or image

Tags: html, image, authentication, md5

Is it possible that if there is a way to identify users with just letting them upload his/her  unique file or image?

It's not a public website service with just 20-30 kids. Just let the logining process be more easier.

I've googled about "file upload authentication" and "file md5 authentication" but there is no clear solution. Please help me with survey instructions, thank you!

Comment: Presumably you could do this the same way you'd do password authentication - store each of your usernames along with the hash of their unique file in a database - then let them upload the file and compare the MD5 hashes.

Answer (score 0):

This would be just another [identification factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication#Factors_and_identity).

Identification factors are something the user

- knows
- has
- is

This is clearly the `has` category.

By php you can use the [md5_file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php) to create an md5 hash of the uploaded file, and you can compare that to the one hash you store in your database. Ofc you still have to encrypt that hash in a proper way, for example with [blowfish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_%28cipher%29).

There are even faster mechanisms, for example you can use a QR code and add the credentials to that. So simply clicking on an image would be enough I think. I am currently not familiar with QR code authentication, but it seems amazing: http://corp.galois.com/blog/2011/1/5/quick-authentication-using-mobile-devices-and-qr-codes.html

There are many questions about QR code under this tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qr-code

Another approach to use a certificate based authentication, but in order to do that you have to configure your webserver and generate private and public keys for the kids.
[Web based login using ssl public/private key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491563/web-based-login-using-ssl-public-private-key)